# Intersection of two intermediate subalgebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

Suppose $B\subset A$ is an inclusion of simple $C^*$-algebras with a conditional expectation of (Watatani) index-finite type and $B^{\prime}\cap A=\mathbb{C}$. Then we know $B^{\prime}\cap A_1$ is finite dimensional, where $A_1$ is the $C^*$-basic construction with respect to the unique minimal conditional expectation. If C and D are intermediate C*-subalgebras, then we know that $e_C\wedge e_D\in B^{\prime}\cap A_1.$ Is it true that $e_C\wedge e_D=e_{C\cap D}$?

Comment: The proof (due to Professor Watatani) has been presented in the following recent preprint (Proposition 4.1): https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.07244

Comment: If it is a definitive answer to your question, then you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Ok, done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following proof is due to Professor Watatani (through private communication). We sincerely thank him for kindly allowing us to present the proof here.

On contrary assume that $e_\mathscr{C}\wedge e_\mathscr{D}\neq e_{\mathscr{C\cap D}}$. Since $e_{\mathscr{C\cap D}}\leq e_\mathscr{C},e_\mathscr{D}$, we have $e_{\mathscr{C\cap D}}\leq e_\mathscr{C}\wedge e_\mathscr{D}$. Let $\mathcal{E}:=\overline{\mathscr{A}}^{\langle\,,\,\rangle_{\mathscr{B}}}$ and $\eta:\mathcal{E}\to\mathscr{A}$ be the canonical inclusion map. There exists some $x\in\mathscr{A}$ such that
$$
\eta(y):=(e_\mathscr{C}\wedge e_\mathscr{D}-e_{\mathscr{C\cap D}})\eta(x)\neq 0\,.
$$
Then, $e_{\mathscr{C\cap D}}\eta(y)=0$ and $(e_\mathscr{C}\wedge e_\mathscr{D})\eta(y)=\eta(y)$. Since $\mathscr{B}^\prime\cap\mathscr{A}_1$ is finite-dimensional and $e_\mathscr{C},e_\mathscr{D}\in\mathscr{B}^\prime\cap\mathscr{A}_1$, we have $(e_\mathscr{C}e_\mathscr{D}e_\mathscr{C})^n$ and $(e_\mathscr{D}e_\mathscr{C}e_\mathscr{D})^n$ converge to $e_\mathscr{C}\wedge e_\mathscr{D}$ in the operator norm topology. Therefore, $(e_\mathscr{C}e_\mathscr{D}e_\mathscr{C})^n\eta(y)$ converges to $(e_\mathscr{C}\wedge e_\mathscr{D})\eta(y)=\eta(y)$ in the Hilbert module norm. Since $(e_\mathscr{C}e_\mathscr{D}e_\mathscr{C})^n\eta(y)=\eta\big((E_\mathscr{C}E_\mathscr{D}E_\mathscr{C})^n(y)\big)\in\eta(\mathscr{C})$, and the Hilbert module norm topology and operator norm topology are identical, we have that $y\in\mathscr{C}$. Similarly, we have $y\in\mathscr{D}$. Therefore, $e_{\mathscr{C\cap D}}\eta(y)=\eta(y)$. This contradicts that $e_{\mathscr{C\cap D}}\eta(y)=0$ and $\eta(y)\neq 0$, which completes the proof.

The above proof has been presented in the following recent preprint (Proposition 4.1): arxiv.org/abs/2311.07244